# How to insert JSON data into MySQL database by invoking Rest API through HTTPClient

Tags: mysql, json, spring, rest, httpclient

I've some JSON data as follows

```
{
                    "className" : "OrganisationGetTest",
                    "methodName" : "initialization",
                    "result" : "SUCCESS",
                    "successCount" : 1,
                    "failureCount" : 0,
                    "skippedCount" : 0,
                    "testRunId" : "TestRunId",
                    "successResult" : "1",
                    "failureResult" : "0",
                    "skippedResult" : "0",
                    "timeToRun" : "4",
                    "failReason" : "",
                    "startDate" : "Fri Jul 01 11:41:50 EDT 2016",
                    "endDate" : "Fri Jul 01 11:41:50 EDT 2016",
                    "TestApp" : "ATF",
                    "TestFramework" : "TestNG",
                    "TestComponent" : "API",
                    "TestSuite" : "OrganisationGetTest",
                    "TestGroup" : "Group",
                    "expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp" : ".*",
                    "expectedExceptions" : "[]",
                    "dataProvider" : "",
                    "dataProviderClass" : "class java.lang.Object",

            }
```

My requirement is to insert this JSON data into MySQL database by invoking POST call of a REST API. I've a working POST call. So I need to invoke that POST call through Spring `HttpClient` and when ever this Post call invokes the JSON data should insert into MySQL.

Can anyone tell is there any way to do it? and one more thing is the we must send JSON data as a single unit.

Comment: So what have you tried?  Right now this is a broad  "gimmie the code" request with a list of requirements, which is not how this site works.  Post your attempt, along with specific problems and you may receive assistance with those issues. Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm not asking for the code. I just asking for a way to do it.